# Create redirect for all pages in a subdirectory

Tags: asp.net, url-rewriting, isapi-rewrite

So far I've been setting up redirects for single pages on my ASP.NET site using ISAPI_REWRITE. These work perfectly well (example below):

```
# Redirect
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Host} ^(?:www\.)?example\.com$
RewriteRule ^/category-1/products\.aspx /category-2/products\.aspx [I, R=301]
```

This will redirect `www.example.com/category-1/products.aspx` to `www.example.com/category-2/products.aspx`.

However, now I want to rewrite this so that ALL requests to a page within category-1 redirect to the identical page on category-2, i.e.  `www.example.com/category-1/allpages.aspx` to  `www.example.com/category-1/allpages.aspx`.

How do I go about this with the RewriteRule?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with this

```
# Redirect
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Host} ^(?:www\.)?example\.com$
RewriteRule ^/category-1/(.*) /category-2/$1 [I, R=301]
```